# Select from table, update the rows selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that selects values from certain rows based on their parameters, then does some calculations and returns the result. I also need to update the rows that were selected. I can only think of ways to do both of these actions with separate queries, but is there a way to do both at once?

Example queries would be:

```
SELECT SUM(a.val1*b.val1) 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.val2 = condition1 AND b.val2 = condition2;

UPDATE a
SET a.val3 = a.val1*b.val1
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.val2 = condition1 AND b.val2 = condition2;
```

Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: Your queries are not syntactically correct.  So, I suppose any query that generated a syntax error would be equivalent to them.  Are you really using MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I am. And the syntax errors are not that extreme that this could have been interpreted as another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no syntax in SQL that allows you to retrieve values and update them in the same query. Use SELECT to retrieve values and UPDATE to change them.

You can use SELECT inside an UPDATE statement as part of the calucalation, but the result will not be the values of what has been updated, only the number of rows that were updated.

Your SELECT statement has a small mistake in it and should be as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(a.val1*b.val1) FROM a, b WHERE a.val2 = 1 and b.val2 = 1;
```

This only returns one row: the sum of the product of val1 columns in tables a and b where the val2 columns meet certain conditions.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve by updating table a with the result of this. If you are looking to set val3 in table a with the product of val1 in tables a and b if the val2 in those tables meet certain criteria, the following might work, but you need to add a join between columns in both tables otherwise val3 will be set to the product of val1 in table a and all the val1 values in table b, which may not be what you want.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.val3 = 
(
SELECT a.val1*b.val1 
FROM b
WHERE b.key = a.key
AND b.val2 = condition2
)
WHERE a.val2 = condition1;
```

Comment: Yes, that fix would actually do what I wanted to illustrate in the example. Thank you for fixing the syntax hiccups and answering my main question, too!

Answer (score 1):

Nope :)
In SQL it is always different queries. You can write a function that will do 2 actions, but never one query.

Answer (score 1):

This will have to be done in two steps - Select and Aggregate then Update.